# Prove that if matrix $A \in M_{n\times n}(K)$ has...

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that if matrix $A \in M_{n\times n}(K)$ has
> (a) $n$ pairs of different eigenvalues belonging to $ K $ then $A$ is diagonalizable over $K$
> (b)exactly one custom value in $ K $ then $ A $ is diagonisable over $ K $ if and only if $ A $ is diagonal

**My try**
(a) If matrix $A \in M_{n\times n}(K)$ has $n$ pairs of different eigenvalues belonging to $ K $ then I have $w(\lambda)=(\lambda-a_{1})(\lambda-a_{2})...(\lambda-a_{n})$.
Then I have $V_{k}=ker(A-a_{k}I)$ for $k \in \left\{1,...,n\right\}$
(b) $w(\lambda)=(\lambda-a_{1})(\lambda^{n-1}+\lambda^{n-2}+...+1)$
Unfortunately I don't have idea how to come to the conclusions.
Can you help me and get some tips?

Comment: what is w(lambda)? Define it clear

Comment: @JossieCalderon $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue belonging for $A$

Comment: and what is $a$? Please define everything.

Comment: @JossieCalderon in (a) I know that $A$ has $n$ pairs of different eigenvalues belonging to $K$ so it is $a_{k}$ for me

Comment: Use the definition of a kernel to arrive at your answers.